# AJAX Post request from Javascript to Python (Django, views.py)

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, post

I am trying to send a POST request from javascript to views.py using AJAX. However, I am getting a 403 Error stating that csrf token is not present.

In order to resolve this issue I followed [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#ajax) and included the function in my javascript. However, I am confused as to what the next step should be.

Any assistance will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simply add somewhere in your template:

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

Then in your js file should be smth like this:

```
var csrf_token;

var sendSomeAjax = function(target) {
    var requestUrl = $(target).data('url');

    return $.ajax({
        url: requestUrl,
        type: 'post',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRFToken': csrf_token
        },
        dataType: 'json'
        // also you can pass some 'data: ' here
    })
};

$(function() {
    csrf_token = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();

    var target = $('.someSelectorWhereYouHavePassedDataUrlToYourView');
    // for example in your template <a href="#" data-url="{% url 'app_url_namespace:view_url_name' %}"</a>

    sendSomeAjax(target).success(function(data) {
        // do smth with data =)
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks madzohan. For me just changing the key of the csrf token from 'csrftoken' to 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' did the job.